# HTTP request debugging: Getting a complete log of all HTTP requests sent by Firefox

Tags: http, firefox, browser

What is the easiest way to obtain a complete log of all HTTP/HTTPS requests issued by Firefox during a browser session?

The question is programming related insofar that obtaining a log of all HTTP/HTTPS requests issued is a great troubleshooting tool when developing webapps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Wireshark is the most complete tool for logging all http activity
- Fiddler tool might be easier to get started with, and comes with built in HTTPS-decryption
- TamperData addon for Firebug is a very good addon for changing the requests ad hoc

Answer (score 3):

Firefox works with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/).

Comment: Yes, Fiddler is great, but it does not work on Mac/Linux unfortunately. What I'm looking for is a cross-platform solution providing Fiddler functionality.

Answer (score 0):

[LiveHttpHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) is a great add-on for Firefox. It traces all the requests along with header information and post data. You can save the log to a file if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Safari has a built in Activity monitor - Window->Activity list all http requests I believe.